# "Couldn't upload. Try again." error on Google Play Console

Tags: android, apk, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

When I try to upload my Android App Bundle to the Google Play Console, I get this generic error message saying "Couldn't upload. Try again.".

I've already tried:

- making sure my `versionName` and `versionCode` are unique among all uploaded artifacts
- making sure that the `.aab`/`.apk` is signed with the proper key
- re-uploading the `.AAB` file
- re-uploading the `.APK` file
- [checking status of google services](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/id6s7g/outage_cant_release_new_app_release_on_google/g277et9?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) to make sure that there isn't a mass outage
- asking my senior Android dev what's up

How do I resolve this error and upload my `.AAB` or `.APK`?

[image: When I try to upload my Android App Bundle to the Google Play Console, I get this generic error message: Couldn't upload. Try again.]

Answer (score 92, accepted):

***Google Chrome***

Use a new **Incognito window** to upload the `.aab` or `.apk` *([as mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64108550/couldnt-upload-try-again-error-on-google-play-console/64110763#comment113385568_64110763))*.

Alternatively, clear the website data:

1. going to: developer console (<kbd>F12</kbd>) > Application > Storage > Clear site data

   - [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIIf0.png)
2. press <kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh the page
3. uploading the `.apk`/`.aab` again

---

***Safari***

Open Preferences >
Privacy > Manage Website Data > Remove All > Done

Comment: This seems to happen when you have accessed multiple Google accounts. Infact, if you jump to gmail, you likely see mailbox from a different account, while you have accessed Play Console with the right one.

Comment: @Eric do you know the root cause of this issue? we tried all approaches mentioned on this questions but not work.

Comment: tried incognito mode and it worked there. Thanks

Comment: For those who still fail using this solution, the problem might be not related to the browser at all.  For me it was a firebase configuration file (google-services.json), copied from another app, overwriting the correct one.

Answer (score 22):

Here's what worked for me:
After getting the error on play console. Now use 'Add from Library' option instead of 'Upload', and you will find your appbundle that failed to upload there, select it and proceed with further steps.

Comment: Worked for me too, tried all the others ways before and nothing was successful, if you get this error start by this solution as it is only 2 clicks ˆˆ

Comment: My app bundle library is empty. How do I get APKs into the library?

Answer (score 9):

This problem comes out due to multiple gmail logins on same browser, if the developer account is not the default logged in account. You can solve this by signing out all gmail accounts and login in the specific gmail account.

Comment: Thanks a ton for this, if anyone was getting the error for uploading an Icon in the console along the lines of 'Can't upload icon. Try again later.' Opening the Play console in Incognito seems to solve the issue (when only a single account is logged in)

Comment: Right. This problem happens in the new Play console when there are multiple google accounts logged in. Google needs to fix this bug.

Answer (score 3):

For my case clearing data, using Incognito or changing browser did not work. So, finally I uploaded an `APK` file (all previous versions were `AAB` files) and surprisingly Google Play console accepted it!

Give a chance to `APK` file if the above answers are not helping you.

Comment: I didn't expect this to work but it surprisingly did. I built an `APK` instead of `AAB` and Play Console accepted it. I don't really know why.

Answer (score 2):

I could simply solve the problem by usinng Firefox instead of Chrome. Nothing else helped. With Chrome the problem remained even after applying all the suggestions above. Chrome 56, OS Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Not sure that this adds anything to the discussion. If you need more help, perhaps consider opening up a new question and linking to this question with further details specific to your issue, including what you have already tried.

Comment: I was using Opera and the switch to FireFox actually helped. Thanks

Comment: Same here. None of the other solutions worked but this one did! And I'm on Windows so it definitely seems to be a chrome issue unrelated to OS.

Answer (score 2):

As of version 119.0.6045.105 of Chrome, I can confidently say that this is about the Chrome. None of the existing suggestions worked. Then I switched to Firefox. It worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have gmail with another account, opened in other tab? If so, sign out from both accounts, then sign in to Google Play console again.

Answer (score 1):

For me, none of the mentioned solutions worked. The issue was that one of the closed testing tracks had an older APK which didn't target API 33, and the target API update duration was overdue. Make sure that all tracks are targeting at least the minimum API version specified by Google.

Answer (score 0):

If your zip align is not successful or verification failed at the end of the zip align process, this error is likely to occur. Please analyze whether zip align was successful. Also, you can try uploading both in .apk and .aab format. You are more likely to get a more detailed error hinting a possible cause.

Answer (score 0):

### If you're using Unity

I was trying to upload a Unity project. Clearing browser cache, loging out of accounts, trying different browsers, zip align etc. didn't help for me. What did, was to either:

### a. Upload an .apk instead of an app bundle.

For some reason, this works completely fine, but app bundles fail every time.

Sadly, apks be unavailable for new apps starting from August 2021 :(

### b. Upgrade to a newer version of Unity

Versions that did not work:

- 2019.4.20

Versions that worked:

- 2020.3.3

Play Console's error message is not especially helpful, so it's difficult to say exactly what the problem was or what fixed it, but hopefully this will help someone else using Unity.

I haven't tested any Unity versions except those listed above. If you have and also have the necessary stackoverflow rights, feel free to update my list with your own findings.

Answer (score 0):

On Safari:

Preferences -> Privacy -> Manage Website Data -> Google (remove that) did it for me! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

After that error happened to me, I click "Add From Library" and my uploaded app bundle showed up there, and am able to select it.

No need to logout/login or clear the cache/cookies.

Answer (score 0):

After All of trying above, I have just Change the browser from Chrome To "Opera" - and its uploaded very fast. It seems that opera is very fast than chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I'll chime in because I had the same error. I was uploading an APK and I got the same error. My browser was Firefox.
When I changed to Safari the error changed to something along the lines of:
Please reduce the size of your APK to 100MB.

So I did what was needed to reduce its size below 100MB. Uploaded again and that resolved the issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using multiple accounts in Google Chrome, try logging into your Gmail on a separate Chrome account, and then attempt to upload the AAB file. This method worked for me:)

Answer (score 0):

Personally what happened in my case is

I opened two gmail accounts in two tabs.One is work and other is personal.

So the upload is not working.So Close all tabs sign out completely and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I often use Chrome to upload, but this time it happened.
And I changed to Safari, working well.

Answer (score 0):

### Expo users, error with app signing

For me the reason for the error on uploading was that **I didn't had signed the build with the same key as my previous build version**.

This happent with expo since I accidentally changed android `package` (bundle identifier) field in app.json to something else than my previous build (it was camel case and I lowercased it)

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me and tried everything from this post. Even changed the version Nothing worked.
Discarded the build and created the new build in Play console and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a VPN issue.

To solve it:

1. Go to Play Console / App Bundle Explorer
2. Push the upload button on the top of the page
3. Turn off your VPN and upload your apk or aab
4. Turn the VPN on and push Done button

Now you can add your aab to the new version