# Playstore: Couldn't upload, try again

Tags: google-play, signed-apk

I'm trying to upload an app to Google Play-Store but I'm getting the error message below without any further comments:

> Couldn't upload. Try again.

I have uploaded numerous apps to Play-Store in the past. I'm not exactly sure why this one isn't going through. The apk in question is a signed-release apk. I'd appreciate some help on this. Kindly find below a screenshot from the Play Store page.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This was a very weird fix but I eventually did it by switching to the old console.** The apk file uploaded successfully immediately I did. The link to the old console can be found on the navigation drawer to the left.

> Drawer > Use classic Play Console

Sadly, Google is killing the old console as from November 2, 2020.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using the **Incognito Mode** worked for me as per this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64110763/1084619)

Comment: Yeah, someone actually recommended this when I had the problem. Thanks. 

Answer (score 1):

For me the reason for the error on uploading was that **I didn't had signed the build with the same key as my previous build version**.

This happent with expo since I accidentally changed android `package` (bundle identifier) field in app.json to something else than my previous build (it was camel case and I lowercased it)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it, here are steps you need to perform

1. Switch to old console
2. Remove any old pending releases
3. Switch back to new console

It should work now!